# Event Observer Module for Upsell

Tags: event-observer

I have created a event observer module that will trigger and remove any product that is **out of stock** from Upsell, but for some reason it is removing the products that are in stock. I have included the module code below and let me know if I am missing anything.

**File name: kevz_upsellobserver.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <kevz_upsellobserver>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </kevz_upsellobserver>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**File name: config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <kevz_upsellobserver>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </kevz_upsellobserver>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <kevzupsellobserver>
                <class>upsellobserver_Model</class>
            </kevzupsellobserver>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_upsell>
                <observers>
                    <kevzupsellobserver>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Kevz_Upsellobserver_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>filterUpsells</method>
                    </kevzupsellobserver>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_upsell>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**File name: Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Kevz_Upsellobserver_Model_Observer {
        public function filterUpsells($observer) {
            $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                if (!$item->getIsSalable()) {
                    $collection->removeItemByKey($item->getId());
                }
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Oberserver.php`:

Change:

```
if (!$item->getIsSalable()) {
```

To

```
if (!$item->isSaleable()) {
```

This should correct your issue.

**P.S.** the reason that *in stock* items are currently being removed is due to the fact that `!$item->getIsSalable()` will return true for every product because that function is not defined anywhere within Magento.

**P.S.S.** If anything, the method could be `getIsSaleable()`

**Edit:** as per comment, to set the column count for product upsell:

In your theme's layout (xml) file `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/layout/yourtheme.xml` file:

```
<reference name="product.info.upsell">
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
        <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: do you mean I need to change `if (!$item->getIsSalable()) {` to `if (!$item->getIsSaleable()) {` ?

Comment: I believe it would need to be `if(!$item->isSaleable())`, you can try both methods though.

Comment: it looks like `if (!$item->getIsSalable()) {` is working fine. P.S. Is there any way to pull static number of products in upsell unless there are less then 4 products assigned to a product as upsell?

Comment: Do you mean `if(!$item->getIsSaleable())`, you keep dropping the 'e'. I don't quite understand what you mean by pulling a static number of products in upsell, can you clarify?

Comment: right now in upsell section (`upsell.phtml`) random number of products are being shown. Sometimes 1, 2 and 4 on every page refresh, but I would like to display 4 products and show less then 4 products only if less then 4 products are assigned as upsell to a product

Comment: I've edited my answer to show where you can set the column count. Magento will always show the maximum amount there, unless a product does not have this amount, in which case it will show that amount of upsells.

Comment: I have already placed that code but it still shows random number of products that us below 4.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: If you've got that code there it should show all four unless your theme controller is setting a random number. Are you sure the products you're seeing with less than 4 only have fewer than 4? Maybe that's why it's displaying that number.

Comment: In first refresh it showed 4 products and again after refreshing it showed 3 products. Its showing random. I have pastes **catalog.xml** at [link](http://pastebin.com/Z2GXTMzS) and **upsell.phtml** at [link](http://pastebin.com/u0dab04V)

Comment: I'm not quite certain what the problem is in this instance, the code that you posted should work correctly unless the collection itself is being assembled incorrectly.

Comment: worked perfectly. Though I had to make few changes to the code.